# Regular expression for an entire word or only some of it

Tags: regex

Trying to find the right regular expression that will match a whole word, for example- "one".
Can I match it to - "o","on","one"
But not for - "or" ?

Thanks

Comment: is oe a valid  match ?

Comment: no, I want to match the exact characters location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
^o(?:n(?:e|)|)$
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/5FycTS/1)